# expressionengine URL rewrite 2.3.1

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

In EE 2.2.2 having this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1 [L]
```

Allowed me to rewrite **domain.com/index.php/view/phone**  to **domain.com/phone**.

In EE 2.3.1 this no longer works. The problem seems to be with **system\codeigniter\system\core\URI.php** and I see few things has changed with this file. If I replace URI.php with the 2.2.2 version then it works again. My question is what has changed and how do I get this to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer

After some time with thoughts (and testing) I've come up with an alternate solution, that might fit your need with the updated EE.

Assuming your rewrite rules are like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, my suggestion is to let your `view` template group be the index template group.
In your index template in the `view` template group, you could have the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="view_channel" require_entry="yes"}
{if no_results}
{embed="a_template_group/my_normal_frontpage"}
{/if}
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
    </body>
</html>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This allows you to, without adding other rewrite rules, have your visitors go to http://example.org/phone and the view/index template will try to find the entry with the entry ID labeled 'phone'. If that entry cannot be found (the `{if no_results}` part) embed another template. In this case I would assume you'd like to show some sort of frontpage.

This also allows you to, under the `view` template group, create ordinary templates like `view/create_entry` which will show up, when you go to http://example.org/create_entry

This should work - and is easy customizable to fit your needs.

Comment: This is exactly what i have in my htaccess. _f and -d are just to tell htaccess to not process files or directories if they exist which is not the case here. This works in 2.2.2 but not in 2.3.1 due to some changes that were done in system\codeigniter\system\core\URI.php.

Comment: Also Pages module is more for static content rather then dynamic. It wont work for me

Comment: I use those .htaccess rules for my own EE 2.3.1 solution and they work for me (and for my clients which also has been updated to 2.3.1 - some of them on different hosting providers). Why is the pages module 'more for static content'? Maybe if you elaborated your solution, I could come with a better suggestion.

Comment: Entries are created by users in the front end using safecracker. No page module involved. I want users to access there entries at domain.com/userentry rather then domain.com/index.php/view/userentry.

Comment: @Pinkie There, I updated the answer to hopefully better fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is not a pretty solution although it may work. I ended up using the older URI.php file from version 2.2.2 which solved this issue. I appreciate your time. I will accept your answer.